# What is the console equivalent of clicking on a command in a markdown file in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, getcwd

I have a `folder` with a `README.md` and a `run.py` that looks like this:

```py
import os


assert __name__ == '__main__'

print('■', __file__)
print('●', os.getcwd())


try:
    os.mkdir('DELETE_ME')
except FileExistsError:
    pass
```

The readme contains the code line `python -m a001_misc.b006_cwd.folder.run`.
PyCharm shows a green triangle next to it.
When I click on it, the output tells me, that `folder` is my CWD.

[image]

This is the desired behavior. (Above all, `DELETE_ME` is created in `folder`.)
But I do not find a one-line console command to reproduce this (i.e. without `cd`).

I would like to know, what actually happens, when I do that click.
The closest equivalent I have found is to do `python -m run` in `folder`.
(While running the whole command in `folder` creates a `ModuleNotFoundError`.)

The readme also contains the code line `python run.py`.
Normally it raises no questions. Clicking it does the same as running the command in `folder`.
But there is a small bug, and maybe it can help to answer the question.
I have renamed the parent of `folder` from `b006_mswitch_confusion` to `b006_cwd`.
But somehow the old name is still connected with this button in the readme.

[image]

Where is that old name still hidden?
(I have already deleted the `__pycache__` in `folder`.)

The example code can also be found [here](https://github.com/entenschule/examples_py/tree/main/a001_misc/b006_cwd/folder).
(The readme file contains the outputs for different ways to run the script.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer and comments by Ahmed AEK contain all the important facts.
Anyway, I think the answer to my question can be simplified to the following:

Clicking on the command will `cd` into the folder of the markdown file and run the command.

But this happens in an environment, where PyCharm has added the project folder to `PYTHONPATH`.

One could say, that **there is no exact console equivalent of the click**,
because there is probably no way to figure out from the console, what PyCharm considers to be the project folder.

Answer (score 2):

a console equivalent in bash would be

```bash
(cd folder; conda activate env or activate venv; path/to/python -m my_script)
```

`my_script` should be found using the `PYTHONPATH`, so for `python -m a001_misc.b006_cwd.folder.run` to work, `examples_py` should be on your `PYTHONPATH`.

since the current directory is always searched first by the interpreter you could just replace it with `python -m run` for portability.

Comment: By `new_work_dir` you mean my `folder`? The command I click on is `python -m path.to.my_script`. You write, that in the console equivalent this becomes `path/to/python -m my_script`. Do you literally mean, that `path.to.my_script` is truncated to `my_script`?

Comment: My question was, what happens when I click on `python -m path.to.folder.run`. Is your answer, that it means `cd path/to/folder` and then `python -m run`? (That does indeed work, and have the same result. But is it really what happens?)

Comment: @Watchduck `a001_misc.b006_cwd.folder.run` is parsed by the interpreter, so `examples_py` should be on your `PYTHONPATH` or `PATH`, the answer is now corrected without the extra noise. i initially misunderstood the question,

Comment: Thanks. So my summary of your answer in the last comment is basically correct?

Comment: @Watchduck yes, that ould be correct.

Comment: I am still surprised, that in the _clicking_ world `python -m path.to.script` and `python -m script` do the same thing. Because in the _console_ world only the short version works from `folder`, while the long version creates a `ModuleNotFoundError`. Is there something worth understanding behind this difference, or does it boil down to "PyCharm does it this way"?

Comment: @Watchduck if `examples_py` is your current "pycharm project folder" then pycharm has added it to your `PYTHONPATH` before calling the interpreter.

Comment: This seems to be the core of the answer to my question. I have created [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76879807/2307570) based on this.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question: In your screenshot, the very first line (printed in blue) is the command that PyCharm executes. In your case, it replaces `python` with a particular Python executable from the virtual environment.

To answer the second question: It can be that the caches of the PyCharm itself are stale, and they have nothing to do with `__pycache__`. Instead, [invalidate the caches in the IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/invalidate-caches.html) by going to **File** > **Invalidate Caches**

Comment: Somehow this command lacks context. When I run it, the CWD is where I run it. For PyCharm the CWD is `folder`. But I can not run it in `folder`, because that creates a `ModuleNotFoundError`. So where does PyCharm run this? And how can I do the same? Invalidating the cache did not work. This even happens when I add the same line to a new markdown file.